# tracing mouse clicks on website

Tags: email, web, click, trace

I am new to website designing and wanted to know couple of things.

1. when some clicks on the link on my website say www.google.com, can i trace that how many people clicked on it.
2. When i send out emails with attachments, can i record how many people opened those attachements. btw this is not yahoo or gmail, its my personal email with an ISP.

if so, please put references so i can read them or explanation if possible

Answer (score 3):

Create the links on your website so that they do a GET to your website first, and then redirect to the desired website.

```
<a href="mywebsite.com?linkto=google.com">Click here</a>
```

The email attachment is a different problem.  If you send an email that reads the attachment from your website, you can record the traffic.

Comment: how can i record these clicks in my database? or is there another way these r stored?

Comment: also can i find out when someone opens my email, wat links are they clicking and how long r they staying on those links? just questions, am sure some wont have an answer. but thatnks for the help

Comment: You would store them in your database.  How this is done depends on the database, and your approach.  Whether you are using a DAL and which one, for example.

Comment: What links are they clicking on: same answer.  Set up the links so they go to your website first.  How long they are staying on the links: If the links are to your website, you can measure the time between page loads.

Answer (score 1):

- For tracking outbound clicks, services like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) can wrap every link on your site with JavaScript and provide statistics and sexy graphs.
- For tracking email attachments, it depends on the attachment. Static files like images can't make callbacks to the Internet, but something like a PDF with embedded JavaScript might be able to.
- As for links within the emails, you can make each link in each email unique by associating a token with each email recipient, e.g. `<a href="http://mysite/page?referrer=e635f56f7dea051c1838a443e065899a">Some Link</a>`. Store the token in a database along with the recipient's email address and later you can cross-reference hits on your site with emails you sent out.

I know there are a handful services that do the latter, but I can't name any offhand. Search for "email newsletter service."

Comment: If I put a link to lolcats.com on my own website, and I have my own website working with Google Analytics, do my analytics reports actually show clicks of the lolcats.com website?  I think the analytics only count when your page is landed on, not when your page is left.  Or am I confused about how Google Analytics works?

Comment: I would have *sworn* that Google Analytics provided something to do this automatically, but I think I'm wrong. A quick search for "google analytics outbound links" turns up snippets of code to do this.